# Would Satan benefit from humans becoming extinct?

Tags: shaitan

Muslims attribute a lot of the mischief in the world to [Satan](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Iblis) (aka Shaitan, Iblis).  Through is wispering (waswas), there seems to be a handful of ways he could influence major catastrophes, such as starting wars.  In an extreme case, these actions could result in mankind becoming extinct.

**Question**: Would Satan benefit from humans becoming extinct?

My impression is that Satan desires disbelief and sin (*...I will surely mislead them all...* [Qur'an 38:82](https://quran.com/38/82)), which would mean that he would not want humans to become extinct, and instead he would prefer humans to reproduce and create many disbelievers.

Comment: Doctrinally, he'll have it the worst for eternity already, and that can't change. How could this benefit him?

Comment: "In an extreme case, these actions could result in mankind becoming extinct." Allah would not allow the extinction of mankind before the Day of Judgement

Comment: @G.Bach That’s the question. Typically Satan is though of as evil, so he might not act rationally (to his benefit). TheZ I didn’t think of that. Human extinction through war would go against signs of the Day of Judgement. Maybe that’s the answer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This seems to be a hypothetical question.

As per many Sahih Hadiths, humans will be still alive when the Last Hour arrives. They are also stated to be the worst of human kind fornicating like donkeys in broad daylight.

> Nawwas bin Sam'an Al-Kilabi said: "The Messenger of Allah (ﷺ)
>   mentioned Dajjal, one morning, as something despised but also
>   alarming, until we thought that he was in the stand of date-palm
>   trees. When we came to the Messenger of Allah (ﷺ) in the evening, he
>   saw that (fear) in us, and said: 'What is the matter with you?' We
>   said: 'O Messenger of Allah, you mentioned Dajjal this morning, and
>   you spoke of him as something despised but also alarming, until we
>   thought that he was in the stand of date-palm trees.' He said: 'There
>   are things that I fear more for you than the Dajjal. If he appears
>   while I am among you, I will contend with him on your behalf, and if
>   he appears when I am not among you, then each man must fend for
>   himself, and Allah will take care of every Muslim on my behalf. He
>   (Dajjal) will be a young man with curly hair and a protuberant eye; I
>   liken him to 'Abdul-'Uzza bin Qatan. Whoever among you sees him, let
>   him recite the first Verses of Surat Al-Kahf over him. He will emerge
>   from Khallah, between Sham and Iraq, and will wreak havoc right and
>   left. O slaves of Allah, remain steadfast.' We said: 'O Messenger of
>   Allah, how long will he stay on earth?' He said: 'Forty days, one day
>   like a year, one day like a month, one day like a week, and the rest
>   of his days like your days.' We said: 'O Messenger of Allah, on that
>   day which is like a year, will the prayers of one day suffice us?' He
>   said: 'Make an estimate of time (and then observe prayer).' We said:
>   'How fast will he move through the earth?' He said: 'Like a rain cloud
>   driving by the wind.' He said: 'He will come to some people and call
>   them, and they will respond and believe in him. Then he will command
>   the sky to rain and it will rain, and he will command the earth to
>   produce vegetation and it will do so, and their flocks will come back
>   in the evening with their humps taller, their udders fuller and their
>   flanks fatter than they have ever been. Then he will come to some
>   (other) people and call them, and they will reject him, so he will
>   turn away from them and they will suffer drought and be left with
>   nothing. Then he will pass through the wasteland and will say: "Bring
>   forth your treasures," then go away, and its treasures will follow him
>   like a swarm of bees. Then he will call a man brimming with youth and
>   will strike him with a sword and cut him in two. He will put the two
>   pieces as far apart as the distance between an archer and his target.
>   Then he will call him and he will come with his face shining,
>   laughing. While they are like that, Allah will send 'Eisa bin Maryam,
>   who will come down at the white minaret in the east of Damascus,
>   wearing two Mahrud[garment dyed with Wars and then Saffron], resting
>   his hands on the wings of two angels. When he lowers his head, beads
>   of perspiration will fall from it. Every disbeliever who smells the
>   fragrance of his breath will die, and his breath will reach as far as
>   his eye can see. Then he will set out and catch up with him (the
>   Dajjal) at the gate of Ludd, and will kill him. Then the Prophet of
>   Allah 'Eisa will come to some people whom Allah has protected, and he
>   will wipe their faces and tell them of their status in Paradise. While
>   they are like that, Allah will reveal to him: "O 'Eisa, I have brought
>   forth some of My slaves whom no one will be able to kill, so take My
>   slaves to Tur in safety." Then Gog and Magog will emerge and they
>   will, as Allah describes, "swoop down from every mound."[21:96] The
>   first of them will pass by lake Tiberias and drink from it, then the
>   last of them will pass by it and will say: "There was water here
>   once." The Prophet of Allah, 'Eisa and his companions will be besieged
>   there until the head of an ox would be dearer to any one of them than
>   one hundred Dinar are to any one of you today. Then, the Prophet of
>   Allah, 'Eisa and his companions will supplicate Allah. Then Allah will
>   send a worm in their necks and the next morning they will all die as
>   one. The Prophet of Allah 'Eisa and his companions will come down and
>   they will not find even the space of a hand span that is free of their
>   stink, stench and blood. They will pray to Allah, and He will send
>   birds with necks like the necks of Bactrian camels, which will pick
>   them up and throw them wherever Allah wills. Then Allah will send rain
>   which will not leave any house of clay or hair, and it will wash the
>   earth until it leaves it like a mirror (or a smooth rock). Then it
>   will be said to the earth: "Bring forth your fruits and bring back
>   your blessing." On that day a group of people will eat from a (single)
>   pomegranate and it will suffice them, and they will seek shelter
>   beneath its skin. Allah will bless a milch- camel so that it will be
>   sufficient for a large number of people, and a milch-cow will be
>   sufficient for a whole tribe and a milch-ewe will be sufficient for a
>   whole clan. While they are like that, Allah will send a pleasant wind
>   which will seize them beneath their armpits and will take the soul of
>   every Muslim, **leaving the rest of the people fornicating like donkeys,
>   and upon them will come the Hour.**'"
>
> [Sunan Ibn Majah 4075](https://www.sunnah.com/ibnmajah/36/150)

Infact there some ulema who use this same reasoning to say that human race will not move to other planets and are confined to Earth. It is also important to remember that Iblees not only tries to make humankind go astray but does so too among the Jinnkind. We have believers & disbelievers among both creations whom Allah will judge as per His Decree.